# Disable ListBox / ListBoxItem Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

I have following ListBox with a DataTemplate.

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" 
      Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Focusable="False" ToolTip="ListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Focusable="False">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Header" Content="{Binding Heading}" Margin="-4,-2,0,0" FontSize="11" Focusable="False"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="myCheck" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-4,5,0"
                      Visibility="{Binding CheckBoxVisibility, Mode=OneTime}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                      ToolTip="Dieses Feld wird in der Lizenz nicht abgefragt."
                      Checked="myCheck_Checked" Unchecked="myCheck_Unchecked"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="InfoText" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" ToolTip="TextBox"
                         Margin="0,-4,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding InfoText}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now to my problem.
[image: Selection problem]

In the picture you can see three elements of my ListBox, E-Mail, Datum and Uhrzeit. The arrows mark where my cursor is located, for the tooltip. When I click on an area which is not the TextBox or the CheckBox something gets selected. Some part of the ListBox, I think. The selected part gets highlighted in blue. I don't want anything to get blue. I have tried with Focusable="False", but that does not work, probably that's not even the right property.

I ran out of ideas on how to find out if it is really the ListBox that gets highlighted, or some other element.

So, any help making the blue go away is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't want any selection at all? Then use an ItemsControl instead of a ListBox.

Comment: ItemsControl does the trick. It even resolves another minor problem I had. Thanks